# kendo grid title change

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to change the title of the kendo grid.

However when i do the below on change event the filtering doesn't work for that column.
I have a sample code here to replicate the issue in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLn5b/4/

```
$("#change").on("click", function() {
$("#grid th[data-field=FirstName]").html("<a tabindex='-1' class='k-grid-filter'     href='#'><span class='k-icon k-filter'></span></a>MiddleName")
})

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    data    : createRandomData(10),
    pageSize: 5,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id       : { type: 'number' },
                FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                LastName : { type: 'string' },
                City     : { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
},
editable  : false,
pageable  : true,
filterable: true,
columns   : [
    { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
    { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" },
    { field: "City", width: 100 }
]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to change the `title` in runtime instead of while creating it? Anyhow, you can do it using:

```
$("#change").on("click", function() {
    $("#grid th[data-field=FirstName]").contents().last().replaceWith("MiddleName");
});
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/nLn5b/5/

Comment: I am not able to change the title by the control's title api in jquery. I will try to replicate the issue in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is more clear this way:

```
$("#grid th[data-field=FirstName]").html("MiddleName");
```

Comment: This works, but removes the filter attribute if you have one on the column header