# I changed Kendo UI Grid column title but no effects on exported excel

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, grid, title

I already checked [kendo grid title change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611267/kendo-grid-title-change) and I changed the column titles with this:

```
$("#grid th[data-field=FieldName]").html("NewTitle");
```

but I'm still seeing the old titles in the exported Excel file.

I also tried to change the nesting th's `data-title` prop and no effects. Did I miss something else?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this from [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-column-titles).
I solved it by simply adding a handler **excelExport** and manually renamed the header titles.
Here's the [complete sample source](http://dojo.telerik.com/@d.madjarov/oNOsO) by Telerik team.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column title like that

`$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns[0].title = "MiddleName";`

Then, your export will have the desirable title.

See the live demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@pnevma/ivUzAX)

Comment: Thank You, Panagiotis! I tried this but it didn't work. I'm using the server binding with **Razor View**. It's little bit different situation. I believe my binding columns are corresponding with _ViewModel_ and _Resource_ classes.